# JSON Parse Date Formats?

Tags: javascript, json, date

Am I correct in assuming that I have to MANUALLY convert Json-encoded date strings to date objects in my client code?

Coming from C#, I took for granted that this was happening automatically, but I guess that was .NET.

Is there a built in mechanism for getting native javascript types from a Json string (for dates, ints, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Scott, yes, it's sad but true.  Don't worry, though, JavaScript programming is still 10 times better than .Net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JSON spec does not define a date data type. That is left up to you.

See Section A.8: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Comment: ... and it makes me quite sad... sad indeed... :(

Answer (score 1):

[JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) does not have a standard date type.  There are various libraries (including .NET) with incompatible extensions for representing it.

Answer (score 1):

see [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) which gives doc on MS implementation

Answer (score 1):

### Auto convert ISO and Asp.net dates date strings to dates

If you use any client-side library like jQuery, you can use my jQuery extension that makes it possible to automatically convert ISO dates and Asp.net dates to actual dates using `$.parseJSON()`.

Check [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html) for code.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() supports replacer param.

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

See [details on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

So you can handle the date type easily in json.

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  return key == "date1" || key == "date2" ? new Date(value) : value;
}

var obj = {
    date1:"5/21/2012 4:49:17 PM",
    date2:new Date()
}
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(jsonString);
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString, replacer);
console.log(jsonObj);
```